# Relative cardinal direction of two coordinates

Tags: c#, algorithm

Following enum is defined:

```
public enum Direction
{
    North,
    South,
    East,
    West,
    Northeast,
    Northwest,
    Southeast,
    Southwest,
    Undefined
}
```

Given two sets of coordinates in two-dimensional space, I'd like to determine the relative cardinal direction from Point 2 to 1.

Examples:

- P1(1,1) and P2(0,1) returns Direction.North as P2 is north of P1
- P1(1,1) and P2(5,4) returns Direction.Southeast
- P1(1,1) and P2(1,1) returns Direction.Undefined

My current approach involves a bunch of conditions, i.e.

```
if (P1.X == P2.X)
{
    // either North, South or Undefined
    if (P1.Y < P2.Y)
        return Direction.South;
    else if (P1.Y > P2.Y)
        return Direction.North,
    else
        return Direction.Undefined;
}
else if (P1.Y == P2.Y)
{
    ...
}
else 
{
    ...
}
```

I'm seeking a shorter and more elegant solution.

Comment: Use the angle of the vector `P2 - P1` (using `arctan2()`), then do something like `if(-15° <= angle <= 15°) return Direction.North` ? (i.e. split the whole thing in numDirections slices then check if the angle lies within an interval). Also I don't understand why if `P1.X < P2.X` is true (meaning the point P1 lies left to P2), why it returns the direction south?

Comment: Is it defined in a standard Cartesian coordinates? If so then shouldn't the first sample be Direction.West, and the second Direction.Northeast?

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski Apparently, the OP is orienting North along the negative X axis, instead of the more usual positive Y axis.  It's odd, but there's nothing in "standard Cartesian coordinates" that dictates the direction of North.

Comment: Can we assume that you want a 45 degree wedge for each of the eight directions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My 3 cents - i'm waiting for improvements

Here is the enum:

```
public enum Direction
{
    North = 0,
    South = 4,
    East = 6,
    West = 2,
    Northeast = 7,
    Northwest = 1,
    Southeast = 5,
    Southwest = 3,
    Undefined = -1
}
```

and the conversion goes as:

```
public static Direction GetDirection(Point p1, Point p2) {
    double angle = Math.Atan2(p2.Y - p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X);
    angle += Math.PI;
    angle /= Math.PI / 4;
    int halfQuarter = Convert.ToInt32(angle);
    halfQuarter %= 8;
    return (Direction)halfQuarter;
}
```

It does not return `Direction.Undefined` however, because

> if y is 0 and x is 0, θ = 0.

(from https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.math.atan2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: For the `Direction.Undefined` bit you could check if  `p1-p2` is close enough to the zero-vector (by means of defining a small epsilon, if the coordinates are floating-point values. if they're integers, then `p1-p2 == (0,0)` can be checked directly. Otherwise, nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have P1 and P2, use transformation `P -> P - P1` to move P1 to origin of 2D space.

Then compute angle between vector `(0,0) - P2'` where `P2'` is transformetd `P2` point (`P2' = P2 - P1`) and X axis.

Use that angle to choose direction (every direction has `360/8` angle width).

Angle between two vectors can be computed using [dot product](https://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/107/vectors/dotcros.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This solution WILL properly return your `Direction.Undefined` when the coordinates are not pointing exactly along one of the directions and it eliminates the nested follow control statements by just examining the angle ([see unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle)). Note that I assumed the point type has its `X` and `Y` properties defined as `int` but this should work alright even if they were defined as floating point type values (E.g., float, decimal or double).

```
static Direction GetDirection(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    double rad = Math.Atan2(p2.Y - p1.Y, p2.X - p1.X);

    // Ajust result to be between 0 to 2*Pi
    if (rad < 0)
        rad = rad + (2 * Math.PI);

    var deg = rad * (180 / Math.PI);

    if (deg == 0)
        return Direction.East;
    else if (deg == 45)
        return Direction.Northeast;
    else if (deg == 90)
        return Direction.North;
    else if (deg == 135)
        return Direction.Northwest;
    else if (deg == 180)
        return Direction.West;
    else if (deg == 225)
        return Direction.Southwest;
    else if (deg == 270)
        return Direction.South;
    else if (deg == 315)
        return Direction.Southeast;
    else
        return Direction.Undefined;
}
```

A simple test...

```
Direction dir;

dir = GetDirection(new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 0));
Console.WriteLine(dir);
dir = GetDirection(new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 1));
Console.WriteLine(dir);
dir = GetDirection(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1));
Console.WriteLine(dir);
dir = GetDirection(new Point(0, 0), new Point(-1, 1));
Console.WriteLine(dir);
dir = GetDirection(new Point(0, 0), new Point(-1, 0));
Console.WriteLine(dir);
dir = GetDirection(new Point(0, 0), new Point(-1, -1));
Console.WriteLine(dir);
dir = GetDirection(new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, -1));
Console.WriteLine(dir);
dir = GetDirection(new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, -1));
Console.WriteLine(dir);
```

Outputs...

```
East
Northeast
North
Northwest
West
Southwest
South
Southeast
```

Note that if the `Point` type defines `X` and `Y` properties as a floating point type then something like the following would return `Direction.Undefined` because it is not EXACTLY pointing east so hopefully this suits your intent...

```
// "Almost" pointing east...
dir = GetDirection(new Point(0, 0), new Point(1, 0.001));
```

Outputs...

```
Undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's break 360 on 8 sectors 45 degrees each. 
So all we need is to find which of 8 sectors a vector (p2 - p1) belongs to:

```
static Direction GetDirection(Point start, Point end)
{

    double dx = end.X - start.X;
    double dy = end.Y - start.Y;


    if (Math.Abs(dx) > Math.Abs(dy))
    {
        if (Math.Abs(dy / dx) <= tan_Pi_div_8)
        {
            return dx > 0 ? Direction.East : Direction.West;     
        }

        else if (dx > 0)
        {
            return dy > 0 ? Direction.Northeast : Direction.Southeast;
        }
        else 
        {
            return dy > 0 ? Direction.Northwest : Direction.Southwest;
        }
    }

    else if (Math.Abs(dy) > 0)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(dx / dy) <= tan_Pi_div_8)
        {
            return dy > 0 ? Direction.North : Direction.South;
        }
        else if (dy > 0)
        {
            return dx > 0 ? Direction.Northeast : Direction.Northwest;
        }
        else 
        {
            return dx > 0 ? Direction.Southeast : Direction.Southwest;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        return Direction.Undefined;
    }


}

static readonly double tan_Pi_div_8= Math.Sqrt(2.0) - 1.0;
```

[Working sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/joLLbf)